# iframe does not load / wierd behaviour on Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe

Im trying to build a simple page, where the user clicks on some 'buttons' which load a corresponding iframe. (url: [gnosi.gr/games](http://gnosi.gr/games))

All is working well on Chrome & surprisnlgy enough on IE as well, however Firefox doesn't seem to load any iframe.

Right now, what I'm doing is having several  elements conatining the 'buttons' users have to click on :

```
<ul>
 <li class="gamelink hangman-game" data-id="1418235" data-game="hangman"></li>
 <li class="gamelink crossword-game" data-id="1418235" data-game="crossword"></li>
 <li class="gamelink bugmatch-game" data-id="1418235" data-game="bugmatch"></li>
 <li class="gamelink hungrybug-game" data-id="1418235" data-game="hungrybug"></li>
</ul>
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.gamesinfo={'crossword': ['Crossword','Fill in the words blah blah'],'hangman': ['Hangman','Try to guess the word 1 letter at a time'],'bugmatch': ['Bug Matc','Eat the bug that corresponds to the answer'],'hungrybug': ['Hungry Bug','blah blah'],'wordscramble': ['Word Scramble','ajoidoas'],'studyslide': ['Study Slide','study the words '],'studymatch': ['Match','do the matching']};
    window.gamesdimensions={'crossword': [950,540],'hangman': [520,540],'bugmatch': [800,500],'hungrybug': [890,600],'wordscramble': [720,400],'studyslide': [1040,800],'studymatch': [752,670]};
    $('.gamelink').click(function(){
        $('#game').html('<iframe src="https://www.studystack.com/i'+$(this).attr('data-game')+'-'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'" width="'+window.gamesdimensions[$(this).attr('data-game')][0]+'" height="'+window.gamesdimensions[$(this).attr('data-game')][1]+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;"><style>#highScoreFrame{display: none!important;</style></iframe>');
        gameloaded($(this).attr('data-game'),$(this).attr('data-id'));  
    })
    $('#togglehelp').click(function(){
        $('#instructions').toggle();
     });
})
function gameloaded(game,id){
$('#instructions').html(window.gamesinfo[game][1]);
$('#game').width($('#game iframe').first().width())
$('#moregames').show();
$('#instructions').hide();
$('#moregames .gamelink').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-id',id);
})
}
```

WIERD BEHAVIOUR:

1. Works fine on localhost
2. If i try to invoke the click event on an element that loads an iframe, typing
   $('.gamelink').eq(4).click()
   in the console, I get nothing, however if i invoke it on one of the first 4 elements, the iframe loads (missing a parameter it will display an error message, but thats fine since the first 4 buttons have that parameter missing on purpose, it is filled in by JS after the first iframe is loaded)

I tried some suggestions i found in similar questions, such as placing an empty iframe with display:none; before the one i want to load, replacing '&' with '&' etc, nothing seemed to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance !